# How to query by number of related models in Loopback/SQL?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, loopback

I have a model Post, with a `HasMany` related model Ratings (also `BelongsTo` Post).

I want to find all of the Posts with more than 200 Ratings.

So far, the only solutions I can think of are:

1. Get all of the posts, and manually filter them with a for loop.
2. Add a column to the Posts table that manually updates as new ratings are added.

(1) is incredibly inefficient (there are thousands of posts), and (2) just doesn't seem right.

I'm using Loopback as a framework and would prefer a built-in solution, but I'm thinking native SQL is the only option here.

Comment: There is an open [related github issue](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/917), so I'm assuming, that this feature is not supported at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Find in Posts, use include rating and where filter by rating gt 200
See docs https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Querying-related-models.html

Comment: But rating is not a property, it's a related model. How would you write a filter to only return posts with more than 200 existing related models (ratings)?